# Filter relation query using bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

How do I retrieve all records using through method but with a condition for the intermediate table, for ex: I want to retrieve all tracks for a channel where is_publish field from album (intermediate table)has value 1

my code so far looks as below:

```
new channelModel({'id': req.params.channel_id})
.fetch({withRelated: ['tracks']})
.then(function (channel) {
    if (channel) {
        res.json({error: false, status: 200, data: channel});
    } else {
        res.json({error: true, status: 404, data: 'channel does not exist'});
    }
})
```

With this code I retrieve all tracks.. And the channel model has a function defined as below:

```
tracks: function () {
    return this.hasMany('track').through('album');
}
```

my database looks smth like this:

channels: id,name,desc

albums:channel_id,name,descr,is_publish

tracks:album_id,name,descr

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I believe you can do the following:

```
ChannelModel = bookshelf.BaseModel.extend({
    tracks: function () {
        return this.hasMany('track').through('album');
    },
    publishedTracks: function () {
        return this.tracks().query('where', 'is_publish', true);
    },
    unpublishedTracks: function () {
        return this.tracks().query('where', 'is_publish', false);
    },
});

new ChannelModel({'id': req.params.channel_id})
.fetch({withRelated: ['pubishedTracks']})
.then(function (channel) {
    if (channel) {
        res.json({error: false, status: 200, data: channel.toJSON()});
    } else {
        res.json({error: true, status: 404, data: 'channel does not exist'});
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you may wish to do this:

```
new ChannelModel({'id': req.params.channel_id})
.fetch()
.tap(function (channel) {
    channel.tracks().query('where', 'is_publish', true).fetch()
})
.then(function(channel) {
    if (channel) {
        res.json({error: false, status: 200, data: channel.toJSON()});
    } else {
        res.json({error: true, status: 404, data: 'channel does not exist'});
    }
});
```

Also, while we're at it, I might point out [`require: true`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-fetch), which is a style I prefer for these situations.

```
new ChannelModel({'id': req.params.channel_id})
.fetch({ require: true })
.tap(function (channel) {
    channel.tracks().query('where', 'is_publish', true).fetch()
})
.then(function(channel) {
    res.json({error: false, status: 200, data: channel.toJSON()});
})
.catch(bookshelf.NotFoundError, function(error) {
    res.json({error: true, status: 404, data: 'channel does not exist'});
});
```

Also note that you were leaving off the call to [`.toJSON()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-toJSON) in your response.

Comment: what does require: true inside fetch() is used for, as I have already seen it somewhere else used...

Comment: `{ require: true }` will throw an exception if the record does not exist. That way you can assume that the body of your `then` function has a record. [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) allows `catch`ing by error type, so you can catch the `NotFoundError` and respond with a 404.